# Is the word "either" required in a "this or that" sentence?

Tags: either-or

Example sentences:

A) You can pick either this or that.
B) You can pick this or that.

Is A, B or both correct?

Comment: Either is correct, but they have subtly different meanings.

Comment: @High Performance Mark - please state what the 'subtly different meanings' are.

Comment: Sentence A means you can pick this or that but not both, whereas in some contexts sentence B could be taken to mean you can pick this or that or both this *and* that.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey: what nnnnnn wrote.

Comment: nnnnnn, which contexts? Please provide at least one.

Comment: **Or**  used between two words or phrases to show that **either of two things is possible** [Longmans Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/or)

Comment: @nnnnnn - I think you are thinking of 'and/or'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey -  Do you want a snack? You can have sultanas or peanuts. (Sometimes when people are offering food at a party, for example, they say "or" but they're not really trying to restrict the choice to only one thing. I'm not thinking of "and/or".)

Answer (score -1):

'Either' can be omitted in a positive construction such as '[Either] James or Mary has hidden the cakes'. In a negative construction, like 'Neither James nor Mary has hidden the cakes', 'neither' cannot be omitted.

[Understanding “Either … Or” and “Neither … Nor”](https://www.dailywritingtips.com/understanding-either-or-and-neither-nor/)

> Or is used between two words or phrases to show that either of two
>   things is possible, or used before the last in a list of possibilities
>   or choices.

[Longmans Dictionary](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/or)

If I say that you can have coffee or tea, I mean that you can have one of these, not both.